# ffmpeg add audio but keep video length the same (not -shortest)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm adding audio to a video file using ffmpeg like so

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav output.mp4
```

However this extends the output video file to be the length of the audio file if it is longer than the video. Using -shortest cuts the video file short if the audio file is shorter than the video. So is there a flag to tell ffmpeg to cut the keep the length of the output video to the length of the input video?

Comment: Please select a correct answer. The only real correct one is the one by @Zurechtweiser.

Answer (score 21):

- If video length is shorter than audio length, `-shortest` is what you want.
- If video length is longer than audio length, no flag at all will  be what you want.

There is no flag to automate this decision.

**EDIT**

Inspired by @deadcode's answer, I need to make clear, that "no flag to automate" is of course not true, if you are **willing to reencode**: In this case go with `apad` as suggested by @deadcode.

If however you want to avoid reencoding (i.e. `-c:v copy`) the answer stands.

There is a workaround using the `ffconcat` demuxer, but it needs a bit of work:

- create a file containing silence in **exactly the same format** as your audiofile ("silence.wav")
- create a concat file "audio.ffconcat" (with as many silence lines as you need to make sure your audio is long enough):

.

```
file 'audiofile.wav'
file 'silence.wav'
file 'silence.wav'
...
file 'silence.wav'
```

- run `ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -f concat -i audio.ffconcat -c:v copy output.mp4`

This will synthesize the `apad` filter without a filter graph, thus allowing a mux without reencoding.

Comment: @RoelVandePaar As I said: If video length is shorter than audio length use `-shortest`, else use this workaround if you want to add silence without reencoding.

Comment: Correct, missed that on review. Removed input. Feel free to do the same.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you can achieve your desired aim by using the -filter_complex option and the apad filter option to pad out your audio with silence at the end if the video is longer.  Your command would be:

`ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav -filter_complex " [1:0] apad " -shortest output.mp4`

This assumes the audio you want is in the first stream of audiofile.wav, the [A:B] syntax says to take the B'th stream from the A'th input (both starting with 0, so [1:0] is the 1st stream from the 2nd input, or audiofile.wav above).

Details at:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-68

Comment: You should mention, that the `-filter_complex` option forces reencoding - it is e.g. possible to run `ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav -c:v copy output.mp4` but not `ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav -filter_complex " [1:0] apad " -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4`

Comment: This is the opposite answer of what is requested. OP asks to end video when audio ends, the answer given is to add audio silence if the audio is shorter then the video. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: It's not "the opposite" of what the OP requested.  The OPs wants the output video to be the length of the input video, regardless of the length of the audio track.  My answer addresses the circumstance where the input video is longer than audio file.  The OP already has a solution for when the input video is shorter than the audio file, which is to use -shortest.

Comment: I am attempting to use `apad` with `-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0`, which is intended to replace the audio of a video with a second audio input. However, using `apad`, causes the stream order to be reversed: index 0 is audio and index 1 is video. Do you have any clue why? This is a problem because it causes lossless concatenation to fail.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to change `-map 0:0 -filter_complex "[1:0] apad" -map 1:0 -shortest` -> `-map 0:0 -filter_complex "[1:0] apad [a]" -map "[a]" -shortest`. You have to sorta redirect apad's output and then map that output _after_ the video. Otherwise the audio track always goes before the video track.

Answer (score 10):

If you know the length of your video-file, you can accomplish that by using

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -i audiofile.wav -t 43 output.mp4
```

Where 43 is the length of your video-file in seconds.

Comment: the author question wants to loop the audio file while the video hasn't finished. Does this work for that?

Comment: @RafaelSanches No, he doesn't.

Comment: The author doesn't want to loop the audio. This answer is also the only correct one which does what the OP was asking; end the video when the input video ends.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, now, the default behavior of current/latest `ffmpeg` via CMD:

```
c:\sbin\ffmpeg.exe -i "D:\video.m4s" -i "\audio.m4s" -c:v copy -c:a copy "D:\combined.mp4"
```

is padding the shorter one.

- If (audio.length < video.length), then it pads the audio with silence, so that `audio.length === video.length`
- If (audio.length > video.length), then it pads the video with the last frame of this video, so that `audio.length === video.length`