# overlay audio files to existing video at specific points

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am currently using a command similar to this: [ffmpeg add audio but keep video length the same (not -shortest)](https://superuser.com/questions/801547/ffmpeg-add-audio-but-keep-video-length-the-same-not-shortest)

I want to be able to add an audio file on top of an existing video (which will have its own audio), at specific points of the video. I also want it to keep the original video length, and the original audio stream of the video.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i video -i audio`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters should make this possible

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to this issue.

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=TIME[s1];[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];[0:a][ac1]amix=2[aout]" -map "[0:v]" -map "[aout]" -shortest OUTPUT
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.